# Scheme - Recursively Adding up Numbers inside a list of list of list of etc

Tags: scheme, racket

I am encountering a issue that I need to add up the second number of each list. For example, suppose I have a list of lists like below,

```
(list (list -4 
        (list (list -1 4) (list 1 7)))
      (list 1 (list (list -2 5) (list 3 3)))
      (list 3 12))
```

Then my job is to add up 4 + 7 + 5 + 3 + 12 = 31. However, the list can have multiple sub lists. But the second item inside a list can either be a number or a list. If it is a list, then we need to dig deeper into this list until we get a number.

Thanks!

Comment: The posted question does does not include any attempt to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and the specific problem you're running into (see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (null? x))
       (not (pair? x))))

(define (my-and x y)
  (and x y))

(define (every? l)
  (foldr my-and #t l))

(define (flat-list? l)
  (cond ((null? l) #t)
        ((every? (map atom? l)) #t)
        (else #f)))

(define (add-only-seconds l)
  (define (l-sec-add l acc)
    (cond ((null? l) acc)
          ((atom? l) acc)
          ((flat-list? l) (+ (second l) acc))
          ((list? l) (apply + acc (map (lambda (x) (l-sec-add x 0)) l)))))
  (l-sec-add l 0))
```

**Example test**

```
(define example-list (list (list -4 
                                 (list (list -1 4) (list 1 7)))
                           (list 1 (list (list -2 5) (list 3 3)))
                           (list 3 12)))

(add-only-seconds example-list) ;; 31
```

I used common-lisp-typical functions `atom?` and `every?`.
Since `and` cannot be used in `foldr`, I defined `my-add` to make `add a function which can be used in`foldr`.